# I keep on getting an error message when I try to read a file via awk. What went wrong?

Tags: bash, awk, substitution

I have 2 HTML files called test1.html and test2.html. The contents of the files are:
test1.html

```
<body>
    <p>Hi!</p>
    <p>How are you?</p>
</body>
```

test2.html

```
<p>Hi!</p>
```

I am trying to execute the below awk command to replace `<p>Hi!</p>` in test1.html with the entire content of test2.html:

```
awk '{sub("<p>Hi!</p>",awk '{print}' test2.html); print}' test1.html
```

But I keep on getting a syntax error message **"awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
awk: 1: unexpected character '.'
awk: line 1: extra ')'"**.
Is there any other way to read the content of test2.html?

Comment: Are you just looking for a solution (this is nearly trivial with `sed`), or are you trying to understand the `awk` error?

Comment: Seems like the easiest way to do this with `awk` is `awk '{sub("<p>Hi!</p>", r)}1' r="$(cat test2.html)" test1.html`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'm looking for a solution but I was having problems with sed so I thought I would try to make it work with awk. either way I do want to know what the reason for the error was.

Comment: You can't just call awk or any other command from awk any more than you could call them from C or fortran. awk is not shell.

Comment: @WilliamPursell it works now. thanks. btw may I know what the functionality of "1" in the code is?

Comment: @niyojet344 The "1" is a shortcut for `{print}`.  It is a common `awk` idiom.  `1` always evaluates to true, and since no rule is given, the default (print) is used.

Comment: @WilliamPursell ok

Comment: Your question says you want to replace `<p>Hi!</p>` with the contents of test2.html which is also `<p>Hi!</p>`. I assume you meant something different to please [edit] your question to fix that. Make sure to include regexp metachars like `.`, `*`, and/or `?` in the string you want to replace in test1.html and backreference chars like `&` in the replacement string in test2.html so you can really test a potential solution. Also, if the original or replacement strings can be multi-line text then include such cases in your example.

Comment: i would've suggested a solution using FS and OFS (so one doesn't have to deal with re-escaping, the risk of that being if somehow the input has multiple instances that needed replacing, then this method would over-do it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems easiest to define a variable with the file content: eg

```
awk '{sub("<p>Hi!</p>", r)}1' r="$(cat test2.html)" test1.html
```

Comment: YMMV depending on the contents of `test2.html`, e.g. if it contains an `&` anywhere then that'll fail, and depending on the string you want to replace, e.g. it would fail with that 2nd line of input due to the `?`.

Answer (score 0):

This task should be trivial with `sed`:

```
sed '/<p>Hi!<\/p>/{r test2.html
                   d
                  }' test1.html
```